# How to turn off layout inspector for Android emulator?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am using a Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 (andrioid-x86 emulator) in Visual Studio code to develop a flutter app. Somehow I entered this layout inspector mode and I don't know how to turn it off.
[image: layout_inspector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am bit late to answer, you can turn off Layout inspector by opening `Dart Devtools` and there you need to toggle **Show Guidelines** button.

Image for reference

[image]

If somehow above solution doesn't work, there might be chance we have added this line by mistake in our `main.dart` --> `showSemanticsDebugger: true`
Just remove the line and we are good to go

Image for reference

[image]